Scrambled SMS alerts are coming in for VM resource utilization metrics in GCP Monitoring
Scrambled SMS alerts are coming in for VM resource utilization metrics in GCP Monitoring. Please advise on how to fix this problem.
Even after adjusting the alert policy reset time, the problem remains unresolved. We've been dealing with this issue for the past few days, and there have been no modifications made to the alert policy.
